# Did I misunderstood

Tags: past-tense

I'm confused about which one of these is correct:

"Did I misunderstood the question?" or "Did I misunderstand the question?"

Not sure why I feel the first one is correct and when searching the phrase I see many people write it like that too, could you help me?
Thanks

Comment: Are you sure they don't write "**Have** I misunderstood the question?" And be careful about saying that you've seen "many people write it like that." Have you actually found that wording in published books and news articles? Or on web discussion boards where people pay little attention to grammar and are often too lazy to fix their mistakes? In any event, perhaps a question like this would be a better fit on [ell.se].

Answer (score 3):

Auxiliary "do" always always always takes the basic form ("infinitive") of the main verb, never a past, a past participle, an '-ing' form, a third person '-s' form or anything else. *Do/did/does understand*.